# Chamar função para alocar vetor em C

Tags: c, array, ponteiro

Olá, estou criando um programa para chamar uma função que deve alocar um vetor para poder ser utilizado na main(), mas estou tendo dificuldade, imagino que eu deva usar um ponteiro para ponteiro, mas não tenho muita experiência com isso. Qual seria o erro cometido por mim? O código é o seguinte:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct pnt{
    int x;
    int y;
}ponto;
void cria_vetor(ponto** conjunto);
int main(){
    ponto* conjunto;
    ponto** ptrconj = &conjunto;
    void cria_vetor(ptrconj);// chamo a função para alocar o vetor
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<5; i++){// imprimo os números do vetor
        printf("\n\tponto %d:\nx = %d\ty = %d", i, conjunto->x, conjunto->y);
    }
    return 0;
}
void cria_vetor(ponto** conjunto){
    *conjunto = (ponto*)malloc(5*sizeof(ponto)); // alocando o vetor
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){//escrevo alguns números no vetor para testar
        (*conjunto)->x = i;
        (*conjunto)->y = 4-i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Há muitas maneiras de fazer isso, mas possivelmente o mais simples é usar o que se chama de _factory function_,  declarando `Ponto* cria_vetor(unsigned tamanho)` por exemplo. E o mais expressivo e fácil para usar seria declarar uma struct Conjunto contendo um vetor com um certo número de pontos, porque afinal é isso que está fazendo. Avise se acha que precisa de um exemplo completo que depois escrevo um

Comment: Você sabe que vai precisar disso, então a primeira função que escreve é uma que mostra os pontos num vetor. "programação defensiva". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você reservou corretamente a quantidade de memória que queria, mas está acessando **a mesma região de memória sempre na funções `cria_vetor` e `main`**:

`cria_vetor`:

```
(*conjunto)->x...
(*conjunto)->y...
```

`main`:

```
conjunto->x...
conjunto->y...
```

O correto seria **incrementar o valor da memória que está no ponteiro referenciado e ir para o próximo item do seu vetor**:

```
(*conjunto + i)->x...
(*conjunto + i)->y...
```

e na função `main`:

```
(conjunto + i)->x...
(conjunto + i)->y...
```

Entenda o código acima como se estivéssemos incrementando um índice de um vetor em uma linguagem de programação de nível mais alto (`conjunto[i]`). Lembre-se de que você não tem um vetor propriamente dito em mãos, e sim **o endereço de memória do primeiro item do vetor, ou seja, um ponteiro**. Se incrementarmos esse valor de memória depois de ter alocado memória suficiente para a quantidade que queríamos (como fez corretamente no começo da função `cria_vetor`), vamos sempre ir para o próximo item a partir do atual pois aquela região já nos foi reservada.

Lembrando também que receberá um erro do seu programa em tempo de execução se tentar acessar um valor acima do que pediu na alocação de memória inicial, como acessar o índice 5 (cinco) do seu array sendo que só vai até 4 (quatro).

Para o resultado final do código, teríamos algo como:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct pnt {
    int x;
    int y;
} ponto;

void cria_vetor(ponto** conjunto);

int main() {
    ponto* conjunto;
    cria_vetor(&conjunto);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        // voltando a acessar os indices que desejamos
        printf("ponto %d:\nx = %d\ty = %d\n", i, (conjunto + i)->x, (conjunto + i)->y);
    }
    
    // lembre-se de liberar toda a memoria heap que usar
    free(conjunto);

    return 0;
}

void cria_vetor(ponto** conjunto) {
    // apontando para o primeiro item e alocando memoria suficiente para cinco
    *conjunto = (ponto*)malloc(5 * sizeof(ponto));

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        // acessando os indices que desejamos
        (*conjunto + i)->x = i;
        (*conjunto + i)->y = 4 - i;
    }
}
```

E a saída:

```
ponto 0:
x = 0   y = 4
ponto 1:
x = 1   y = 3
ponto 2:
x = 2   y = 2
ponto 3:
x = 3   y = 1
ponto 4:
x = 4   y = 0
```

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.